# Passing a closure as argument in a recursive function in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to implement the map function in Swift. But I'm stuck with an error

> at map(**f**, ...): Cannot convert value of type 'T -> U' to expected argument type '_ -> _'

```
func map<T, U>(f: T -> U, _ list: [T]) -> [U] {
    return list.isEmpty ? [] : [f(list.first!)] + map(f, list[1..<list.count])
}
```

Comment: First, you state your function returns `[U]` but then say `return list.isEmpty ? []`

Comment: @sschale Yes. [] doesn't affect the return typing. The error occurs at the recursive call map(f, ...)

Comment: There's already a `map` method on the `Array` type... what are you trying to do...

Comment: I am just implementing a map function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is misleading. The problem is that
`list[1..<list.count]` returns an [`ArraySlice`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_ArraySlice_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/struct/s:VSs10ArraySlice), not an [`Array`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Array_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/struct/s:Sa),
so that the recursive call does not match the parameter types.

A possible solution: Create a "real" array from the array slice:

```
func map<T, U>(f: T -> U, _ list: [T]) -> [U] {
    return list.isEmpty ? [] : [f(list.first!)] + map(f, Array(list[1..<list.count]))
}
```

(I assume that you try this for educational purposes, as there is
already a `map()` methods for collection types.)

Comment: `The error message is misleading.` a frequent problem in Swift